# C++ why no .lib file created?

Tags: visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to create a dll. But cannot find the corresponding .lib file. Why? I need that file to put it into my tester.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to post some code or project settings. .lib files are only created when __declspec(dllexport) is used.

Comment: NB: If you don't have this in there, it will silently fail to create the associated .lib file!

Comment: There is no silent failure. Using another mode of DLL function exporting simply does not require a .lib file to operate.